# "Snapping" the Results of t-sne to a Regular Grid - Scalability Issues

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, data-visualization, hungarian-algorithm

I'm trying to use t-sne to arrange images based on their visual similarity, similar to this cool example for emojies ([source](http://prostheticknowledge.tumblr.com/post/114329848096/1053-emojis-ordered-by-similarity-visualization-by)):

[image]

but the output of t-sne is just a "point cloud", while my goal is to display the images in a regular, near-square, dense grid. So I need to somehow convert the output of t-sne to (x,y) locations on a grid.

So far, I've followed the suggestion in [this great blog post](https://blog.sourced.tech/post/lapjv/): I formulated it as a linear assignment problem to find the best embedding into a regular grid. I'm pleased with the results, for example:

[image]

**My Problem is that the "snapping to grid" stage turns out to be a huge bottleneck, and I need my method to scale well for a large number of images (10K)**. To solve the linear assignment problem I'm using a Java implementation of the Jonker-Volgenant algorithm, whose time complexity is O(n^3). So while t-sne is nlogn and can scale well up to 10K images, the part of aligning to a regular grid can only deal with up to 2K images.

*Potential Solutions*, as I see it:

1. Randomly sample 2K images out of the total 10K
2. Divide the 10K images into 5 and create 5 maps. This is problematic because there's a "chicken and egg" problem, how do I do the division well?
3. Trade accuracy for performance: Solve the Linear assignment problem approximately in a near-linear time. I want to try this but I couldn't find any existing implementations for me to use.
4. Implement the "snap to grid" part in a different, more efficient way.

I'm working with Java but solutions in cpp are also good. I'm guessing I'm not the first to try this. Any suggestions? Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: How long does it currently take to complete?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?